# Can i use AVAssetWriter in place of AVExportSession?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, avassetwriter, avasset

I want to crop the video given the lenght and width and x and y coordinates and it seems its not at possible with avmutablecomposition so I am planning to use `AVAssetWriter` to crop video using its aspectFill property in video setting.

BUT MY QUESTION is can we use `AVAssetWriter` as a replacement for `AVExportSession` ??

If yes, how to initialise the `AVAssetWriterInput` with `AVAsset` object as that we do in `AVExportSession`,Like this

```
[[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:videoAsset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s possible that what you are looking for is AVMutableComposition naturalSize property which from what it looks from here, allows scaling (not cropping) of the video to wished sizes.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVMutableComposition_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVMutableComposition/naturalSize